# Convert .osm file to .map

Tags: dictionary, openstreetmap, osmosis

I have tried to convert .osm file to .map I have followed steps and configure osmosis, i have tried with 0.44.1(latest one) as well as 0.41.1.

I have followed many tutorials and tried to debug but didn't get specfic results. If somebody have idea please help me out this problem.

- osmosis.bat compiled sucessfully
- but after I compile this command it gives me error

  ```
  osmosis --rx file=e:/Android_Saveen/Andriod/Mysure/soft/india-     latest.osm.pbf
  --mapfile-writer  file=e:/osmosis/osmosis-0.41/osmosis-0.41/bin/myu.map 
   bbox=12.3836,76.5610,12.197176.7663 type=hd
  ```

Here is another command I tried :

```
osmosis --rx file=mysuru.osm --mapfile-writer file=mysuru.map type=hd
```

> SEVERE: Execution aborted.
>   org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: Task type mapfile-writer
>   doesn't exist.

If I copy map-writer jar into lib under default then it gives me this error:

> SEVERE: Thread for task 1-rx failed.

Comment: What .map file format are you referring to?

Comment: i have just done this problem

Comment: It would help others describing how you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got solution of this problem:

I have used `cmd` to extract `.pbf` file to `.map` file with respective lat lng.

[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mapsforge-dev/psEJG46Qx3k) you can see one person Emux help me out this problem.
I really appreciate it.

The correct command is:

```
osmosis --rb file=india-latest.osm.pbf --mapfile-writer file=area.map bbox=12.2001,76.4964,12.4054,76.8452 type=hd
```

We can change `type=hd` to `type=ram`, if there is enough RAM. Otherwise it'd give us an out-of-memory error. By this method require more heap size.